# recursively select rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I'm using postgresql and I tried try to understand how to select recursive.
I made a example table like below, if `tagId` is 5 how to select recursively up until `ParentTagId` null (get 1,3,5 rows) ?
and if `tagId = 1` how to select recursively down (get 1,3,4,5 rows)?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Tag"(
"TagId" SERIAL NOT NULL,
"ParentTagId" integer,
"Name" varchar,
PRIMARY KEY ("TagId")
);

TagId | ParentTagId | Name |
1     |             | 1a   |
2     |             | 1b   |
3     | 1           | 2a   |
4     | 1           | 2b   |
5     | 3           | 3a   |


var tagId = 5;

var selectTagRecursiveUp = function(tagId) {
  var query = 'SELECT * FROM "Tag" WHERE "TagId" = $1';
  dbClient.query(query, [tagId], function(error, result) {    
  });
});
```

Comment: you need `ltree` extension for your postgresql. Having it you can write queries like `select * from "Tag" where path @> '1.3.5'` which means get all ancestors of Tag with id=5 or `select * from "Tag" where path <@ '1'` to take all descendant of Tag with id=1.

Comment: @stas Thanks for reply!  I'm google now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a [recursive common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
with recursive tag_tree as (
   select "TagId", "ParentTagId", "Name"
   from "Tag"
   where "TagId" = 5
   union all
   select parent."TagId", parent."ParentTagId", parent."Name"
   from "Tag" parent
     join tag_tree child on parent."TagId" = child."ParentTagId"
)
select *
from tag_tree;
```

To walk the tree in the other direction, you just use a different "anchor" query and swap the join condition in the recursive part:

```
with recursive tag_tree as (
   select "TagId", "ParentTagId", "Name"
   from "Tag"
   where "TagId" = 1
   union all
   select child."TagId", child."ParentTagId", child."Name"
   from "Tag" child
     join tag_tree parent on parent."TagId" = child."ParentTagId"
)
select *
from tag_tree;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5ed10/1

---

<sup>Note that is usually not such a good idea to use quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble then they are worth it</sup>

Comment: Thanks for reply! I tried first one query I get error `[error: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0]`

Comment: @user1575921: no idea, that is not a Postgres error message. Where and how did you run that?

Comment: my fault I forgot param I'm checking again now

Comment: works great ! have few question if  one row have many column is this the only way select all ,  write down each column like `select "TagId", "ParentTagId", ...` and `select child."TagId", child."ParentTagId",` ?

Comment: and you mention don't use quoted identifiers, does that mean I have to name the column small case ? I don't have much db design experience, usually you use small case underline not camelcase in column name? if use uppercase(quote identifiers) what kind of trouble will be happen?

Comment: @user1575921: probably not much "trouble", but many tools do have problems with quoted identifiers and I personally find it terrible having to type those quotes all the time. I prefer `tag_id` of `tagid` or `"TagId"`